# The limiting of php/mysql outcome from the table(probably easy thing)

Tags: php, sql, database

Good day,
I have a problem with following code, I have to limit companies ID_CL (it`s outcome). I want to limit the display to the only one ID_CL (one because , right now it displays everything) is it possible ?

Sorry for stupid question, I usually don't work with mysql/php

````
            {
                //$size_h =1;
               
                list($list_num, $size_w, $size_h) = $this->getImageDefSize('list');

                //$table = TB_JOB." jb LEFT JOIN ".TB_CL." cl USING(".ID_CL.") ";
                $table = TB_JOB." jb LEFT JOIN ".TB_CL." cl USING(".ID_CL.") ";

                $field = "jb.".ID_JOB.", jb.job_code, jb.shop_name, jb.job_name, jb.intro, jb.video_url, jb.salary, jb.area_0, jb.area_1, jb.area_2, jb.biz_0, jb.biz_1, jb.biz_2, jb.emid, jb.tel, jb.email, jb.access, jb.nenshu_range, jb.sv_1, jb.company, jb.worktime, jb.holiday";
                $field .= ", jb.rail_1_0, jb.rail_1_1, jb.rail_1_2, jb.rail_2_0, jb.rail_2_1, jb.rail_2_2, jb.free_1_0, jb.free_1_1, jb.free_2, jb.free_3, jb.moddate, jb.regdate, jb.contents, jb.qualification,jb.zip,jb.pfid,jb.address1,jb.address2";
                $field .= ", cl.".ID_CL.", cl.cl_name, cl.business, cl.email AS client_email ";
                //$field .= ", cl.".ID_CL.", cl.cl_name, cl.business, cl.email AS client_email ";

                
                if (! empty($_SESSION["srch"]["new"])) {
                    $od = " ORDER BY jb.setdate DESC, cl.rank, jb.jobid ASC";
                
                } else {
                    $od = " ORDER BY cl.rank, jb.moddate DESC, jb.jobid ASC";
                }

                
                //$total = $this->countTB($table, ID_JOB, $this->wh);
                $total = $this->countTB($table, ID_JOB, $this->wh);
            

               \
                if ($total > 0) {
                   // $_SESSION["srch"]["idlist"] = $this->arrayTB($table, ID_JOB, $this->wh.$od);
                    $_SESSION["srch"]["idlist"] = $this->arrayTB($table, ID_JOB, $this->wh.$od);```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use MySQL LIMIT for this purpose.

According to your query, After **, jb.jobid ASC** you should add **LIMIT 1**

This will help you.

Comment: Hello friend, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Job.class.php (835): 'jb.jobid, jb.job_code, jb.shop_name, jb.job_name, jb.intro, jb.video_url, jb.salary, jb.area_0, jb.area_1, jb.area_2, jb.biz_0, jb.biz_1, jb.biz_2, jb.emid, jb.tel, jb.email, jb.access, jb.nenshu_range, jb.sv_1, jb.company, jb.worktime, jb.holiday, jb.rail_1_0, jb.rail_1_1, jb.rail_1_2, jb.rail_2_0, jb.rail_2_1, jb.rail_2_2, jb.free_1_0, jb.free_1_1, jb.free_2, jb.free_3, jb.moddate, jb.regdate, jb.contents, jb.qualification,jb.zip,jb.pfid,jb.address1,jb.address2, cl.clid, cl.cl_name, cl.business, cl.email AS client_email ' Debug of  $field